# Position of Button with centerInParent enabled. Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1">
    <Button
        p1:layout_width="101.5dp"
        p1:id="@+id/Start"
        p1:text="@string/StartBtn"
        p1:layout_height="101.5dp"
        p1:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <WebView
        p1:layout_centerInParent="true"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/Sky" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So i have that for example and i would want to get the x/y coords of the button. How can i do it? Or the height of the container so i can calculate it. Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels is not usefull as it returns the size of the screen.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more ? You want to get the Co-ordinates in some method in Activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetLocationInWindow](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.GetLocationInWindow/p/System.Int32[]/) or [GetLocationOnScreen](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.GetLocationOnScreen/p/System.Int32[]/) to get the button location. You need to pass a two element array which will be populated when these methods return.

You can also use [Left](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Left/) and [Top](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Top/) to get X and Y of the button relative to the parent.